Prove that the set of points $z_i$ form a limited set in $X$
Let $X$ be a Banach space and $M$ is a subspace of $X$. For each point $z$ of $X$, let us consider the function
$f(m) = \|z - m\|^2$, $\quad m \in M$,
and we equip the set of these functions with the usual order:
$f_{z_1} \geq f_{z_2}$, if $f_{z_1}(m) \geq f_{z_2}(m)$, for all $m \in M$.
if $f_{z_i}$ is a fully ordered family, we have:
$$||z_j-m||\leq ||z_i-m||, j>i, m\in M$$
and the points $(z_i)$ then form a limited set of $X$.
How can I prove this fact, that the set of points $z_i$ form a limited set in $X$?
Or if you could show that you fixed a point $z_0$, and possibly show that $z_i\geq z_0$ for all $i\in I$?
Could anyone help me prove this fact?
Thank you for the help

What is $M$?$~$

@leoli1 $M$ is a subspace of $X$

By 'limited set' do you mean bounded set? If so, the statement is not true

@leoli1 That's right, but I wanted to know if you could show that you fixed a point $z_0$, and possibly show that $z_i\geq z_0$ for all $i\in I$?
